# Equivalent of `continue' in `cl-loop'?

Tags: elisp, cl-lib, iteration, loop-facility

Does the `cl-loop` macro implement an equivalent to the `continue` keyword of other languages?

The behavior of `break` can be achieved by using `until` or `while` clauses by placing them in the middle of `cl-loop`, e.g.

```
(cl-loop item in '(1 2 3 4)
         do (print item)
         until (= 3 item)
         do (print item))
```

will be roughly equivalent to Python code

```
for item in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    print(item)
    if item == 3:
        break
    print(item)
```

However, I cannot identify any clause, that says "abort this iteration step, continue with the next", like the `continue` keyword would do. Is there such a clause?

### Usage example

Let's say I want to do something for every string in a list.  From the string I want to derive a file-name, and if it exists, collect data about those files.

With a `continue` clause:

```
(defconst mylist '(1 2 "hello" 3 "world" 4))

(defconst mylist-file-data 
  (cl-loop for prefix in mylist
           unless (stringp prefix) continue
           for file-name = (concat prefix ".txt")
           unless (file-exists-p file-name) continue
           for attributes = (file-attributes file-name)
           for mtime = (file-attribute-modification-time attributes)
           for size = (file-attribute-size attributes)
           collect (list file-name mtime size)))
```

By contrast, without a `continue` clause I cannot use `for` clauses to define variables, that can only be defined when the condition is fulfilled. Instead I need to reformulate the loop more awkwardly, e.g. as

```
(defconst mylist-file-data
  (cl-loop for prefix in mylist
           for file-name = (if (stringp prefix) (concat prefix ".txt"))
           for attributes = (if (file-exists-p file-name) (file-attributes file-name))
           for mtime = (if attributes (file-attribute-modification-time attributes))
           for size = (if attributes (file-attribute-size attributes))
           if attributes
           collect (list file-name mtime size)))
```

Note how all `(if ...)`s are executed for each iteration step, even when the first already decides that the step could be skipped.

Comment: Not an answer, but the `cl-loop` macro is an elisp implementation of Common Lisp's `loop` macro.  You could read up on the latter in [this chapter from "Practical Common Lisp"](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) to see if the construct you want is available in some form.

Comment: @Dan No such luck. But `cl-loop` contains many Emacs specific extensions, so I may hope.

Comment: `catch/throw` are general (if low-level) mechanisms to implement alternative control structures (like `break` and `continue`). How to fit them into `cl-loop` however is beyond me: I don't understand `cl-loop`...

Comment: @NickD Not applicable in `cl-loop`. With plain elisp it would be something like `(catch 'break (while COND (catch 'continue BODY)))`.

Comment: That's not quite true: there is an implicit block defined with `cl-loop` (nil by default but it can be named if you want) and `cl-block` is a macro that sets up a `catch` with that name; then `cl-return-from` does a `throw`. That's basically a `break`. I still don't know how to do a `continue` though (not even in the `while` case: your example is wrong I think because `continue` should evaluate the `COND`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for short-circuiting logic, e.g. nothing proceeds after one condition fails, I think you need to use something like the and macro. I don't know a way to do this other than to let bind some variables, and use setq inside the loop like below. The attributes line will only be set when the file-name exists here.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defconst mylist '(1 2 "hello" 3 "world" 4))

(let (file-name attributes)
  (cl-loop for prefix in mylist
       when (and (setq file-name (and (stringp prefix) (concat prefix ".txt")))
              (file-exists-p file-name)
              (message "getting attributes for %s" file-name)
              (setq attributes (file-attributes file-name)))
       collect
       (list file-name
         (file-attribute-modification-time attributes)
         (file-attribute-size attributes))))
#+END_SRC
```

It isn't quite continue like you want, but is functionally the same I think. The only benefit of this over your solution above is the short-circuiting logic though.

Building on the `dolist` example that @Drew suggested below, here is a version that uses `when-let*` which I think also short circuits itself and stops evaluating its arguments on the first nil value.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (defconst mylist '(1 2 "hello" 3 "world" 4))

  (setq result ())

  (dolist (prefix  mylist)
    (when-let* ((p0 (stringp prefix))
        (file-name   (concat prefix ".txt"))
        (p1 (file-exists-p file-name))
        (attributes  (file-attributes file-name))
        (mtime       (file-attribute-modification-time attributes))
        (size        (file-attribute-size attributes)))
      (message "fn: %s" file-name)
      (push (list file-name mtime size) result)))
  result
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Using `if/unless` clauses is too limited. Let's say I want to iterate over a list, and for all strings in the list perform further computations. With a `break` clause that would be `(cl-loop for item in items unless (stringp item) break for foo = (bar item) ...)`. Using `unless (stringp item)` I can only chain accumulation and `do` clauses, but cannot use any `for` clauses and have to connect the clauses with `and`.

Comment: you should provide an actual example of what you want to do. The example I showed is equivalent to using continue in a Python loop.

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 1):

This "answer" is not meant to be an the answer to the question because it is not "using cl-loop". But rather provide an alternative (as many other answers have done already).

I would recommend using [loopy](https://github.com/okamsn/loopy). According to its readme, Loopy is an (external) emacs package that provides a "a macro meant for iterating and looping [that is] similar in usage to ~cl-loop~ but uses symbolic expressions rather than keywords."

It already has a `continue` command (whose alias is "skip"). Here is the relevant section of it's manual:

```
2.2.4.2 Skipping an Iteration
.............................

‘(skip|continue)’
     Go to next loop iteration.

          ;; => (2 4 6 8 12 14 16 18)
          (loopy ((seq i (number-sequence 1 20))
                  (when (zerop (mod i 10))
                    (skip))
                  (when (cl-evenp i)
                    (push-into my-collection i)))
                 (finally-return (nreverse my-collection)))
```

For the specific loop you posed as an example, I think this is the equivalent as `loopy` loop. Pretty straightforward translation.

```
(loopy ((list prefix mylist)
    (unless (stringp prefix) (continue))
    (expr file-name (concat prefix ".txt"))
    (unless (file-exists-p file-name) (continue))
    (expr attributes (file-attributes file-name))
    (expr mtime (file-attribute-modification-time attributes))
    (expr size (file-attribute-size attributes))
    (collect (list file-name mtime size))))
```

One Caveat: loopy is still in its infancy and is currently undergoing some change in its syntax (see [#33](https://github.com/okamsn/loopy/issues/33)). However, it is more than usable and these changes will make it even more similar to `cl-loop` and easier do nested loops with.

Answer (score 1):

As @NickD pointed out, you can also use `cl-block` and `cl-return-from` to simulate `continue`.

```lisp
(cl-loop for item in '(1 2 3 4)         
    with items                          ;; declare variable `items'
    do (cl-block 'iteration             ;; put the iteration body in a block  
        (when (= 3 item)
          (cl-return-from 'iteration))  ;; jump out the whole iteration if item = 3
        (push item items))              
    finally return (nreverse items))    ;; return '(1 2 4)
```

In the same spirit, your example could be implemented like this:

```lisp
(defconst mylist-file-data 
  (cl-loop for prefix in mylist
           with file-data-list
           do (cl-block 'iteration
                (let (file-name attributes mtime size)
                  (unless (stringp prefix)
                    (cl-return-from 'iteration))
                  (setq file-name (concat prefix ".txt"))
                  (unless (file-exists-p file-name)
                    (cl-return-from 'iteration))
                  (setq attributes (file-attributes file-name))
                  (setq mtime (file-attribute-modification-time attributes))
                  (setq size (file-attribute-size attributes))
                  (push (list file-name mtime size) file-data-list)))
            finally return (nreverse file-data-list)))
```

Or, to get rid of those `setq`

```lisp
(defconst mylist-file-data 
  (cl-loop for prefix in mylist
           with file-data-list
           do (cl-block 'iteration
                (let* ((prefix-string? (unless (stringp prefix)
                                         (cl-return-from 'iteration)))
                      (file-name (concat prefix ".txt"))
                      (file-name-exists? (unless (file-exists-p file-name)
                                           (cl-return-from 'iteration)))
                      (attributes (file-attributes file-name))
                      (mtime (file-attribute-modification-time attributes))
                      (size (file-attribute-size attributes)))
                   (push (list file-name mtime size) file-data-list)))
           finally return (nreverse file-data-list)))
```

But at this point, @John Kitchin's answer using `when-let*` looks similar but cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question about CL's `loop`.  But it shows you another, simple way to do what you apparently want to do.

```lisp
(let ((result  ())
      file-name attributes mtime size)
  (dolist (prefix  mylist)
    (unless (stringp prefix)
      (setq file-name   (concat prefix ".txt")
            attributes  (file-attributes file-name)
            mtime       (file-attribute-modification-time attributes)
            size        (file-attribute-size attributes))
      (push (list file-name mtime size)))))
```

And if you really do want to break out of the loop at any point (instead of `continue`ing), just wrap the `dolist` in a `catch`, and then `throw` to that catch, throwing it whatever value you like.

Comment: I think if you use when-let* inside the dolist it would be closer to the short-circuiting logic the OP was looking for.

Comment: @JohnKitchin: What short-circuiting? I thought he wanted to just continue, skipping the actions for that iteration and continuing with the next iteration. (And it's not clear to me how you are suggesting to use `when-let*` in the `dolist` - using it to do what?)

Comment: My interpretation was he wanted to continue after the first failed  logic, e.g. if the file doesn't exist, i.e. to not also check all the following conditionals. That is I believe what happens in the and macro, where it returns nil at the first nil conditional and does not evaluate the rest of them. I added the idea with when-let* in my answer above.